# inline divs that adjust width automatically

Tags: css, html, dynamic, width

In case of 2 divs. one is static and other is dynamic. That is one div width should be 400px (This one I call as static div as it has static width) and the other div should occupy the rest width (This one I call as dynamic div as it has dynamic width). And, the dynamic div has no fixed width and should occupy all the remaining and should float right where as static div floats on left. My main issue is while stretching the browser when the website is active, there comes the major issue. I neither want the divs to overlap or go down. I want the dynamic div's width to adjust such that the menus remain constant.

My example code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        margin:0px;
    }
    #wrap{
        width:100%;
        min-width:1000px;
    }
    #static{
        width:400px;
        float:left;
        background-color:#930; /* Just to differentiate DIV */
    }
    #dynamic{
        float:right;
        background-color:#CF0; /* Just to differentiate DIV */
    }
    .menus{
        display:inline-block;
        padding-left:5px;
        padding-right:5px;
            width:80px;
    }
</style>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="static">
        Logo comes here
    </div>
    <div id="dynamic">
        <div class="menus">
            Menu1
        </div>
        <div class="menus">
            Menu1
        </div>
        <div class="menus">
            Menu1
        </div>
        <div class="menus">
            Menu1
        </div>
        <div class="menus">
            Menu1
        </div>
        <div class="menus">
            Menu1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, menus are displayed pretty far from logo whereas I need them to be just besides logo (but shouldn't be float left.) And, the width of the dynamic div should be adjusted such that they are displayed without wasting space.

If this is out of CSS then anybody please suggest me with JS/jQuery code.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `float:right` from `#dynamic`:

[JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/emulux/1)

---

To evenly distribute the menu items, do this:

```
#dynamic
{
    background-color:#CF0; /* Just to differentiate DIV */
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}

.menus
{
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
}
```

JS Bin demo: http://jsbin.com/emulux/2

---

A third installment...

Set a percentage width on the static div like 20% and set 80% to the dynamic div:

```
#static
{
    float:left;
    background-color:#930; /* Just to differentiate DIV */
    width: 20%;
}

#dynamic
{
    background-color:#CF0; /* Just to differentiate DIV */
    display:table;
    width: 80%;
}

.menus
{
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/emulux/3)

Comment: Cool, but how can I adjust the menus so that they will have equal padding?

Comment: Equal padding? You mean the first menu margin-left?

Comment: Not actually, in your JSbin menus looks like they are aligned to left. I don't even need it to align in center but I need it to be aligned in such a way that all menus are equally occupying the space between each such that there will be no waste space in dynamic Div

Comment: Cool, can you tell me how can I achieve it?

Comment: Cool, thanks but still there is waste space on the right side. I need menus to cover all the space in dynamic div.

Comment: Waste of space on the right side? I don't get it... If you look at the JS Bin demo, the menu `<div>`s are evenly spaced inside a table like structure. Each `<div>` is like a table cell and its content is centered. In my screen the `#dynamic` div expands to occupy all the available space to the right...

Comment: Oops in http://jsbin.com/emulux/2 something what I am looking for but the dynamic div should be in the same line with the static div.

Comment: In my screen they're on the same line... :)

Comment: How come Dynamic Div show in the same line to Static Div. Dynamic Div goes down the Static Div as you gave width of Dynamic Div 100%.

Comment: Cool. That's fine. I just been checking http://jsbin.com/emulux/2 Now it got it :)

Answer (score 0):

THis should do the trick..

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZS2tH/1/)**

```
 #static{
        width:400px;
        float:left;
        background-color:#930; /* Just to differentiate DIV */
        display:inline; /*New Line */
    }
    #dynamic{
      /*  float:right;*/
        background-color:#CF0; /* Just to differentiate DIV */
        width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: Cool, but how can I adjust the menus so that they will have equal padding, in your JSbin menus looks like they are aligned to left. I don't even need it to align in center but I need it to be aligned in such a way that all menus are equally occupying the space between each such that there will be no waste space in dynamic Div

Comment: @RockStar do you want it like http://jsfiddle.net/ZS2tH/2/ ?? The extra space as you say is becuase width:80px; for Menu class in css
If this solved your problem please accept as answer

Comment: I want menus to be spread such that they start from left and till the right and occupies all the space and should adjust upon contracting the website width and shouldn't overlap at the same time. In your output there either comes waste space in left of dynamic div or right of dynamic div. I don't want to see waste space. I need menus to cover all the dynamic div width.